# Sharing data from two text file using by 2 application at same time

Tags: c#, wpf, file-sharing

I have two WPF application i use the same text file in two applications when i want file to write from one application and read the data written from another application .
but i can't do it because the two applications use the same file at same time .
can any one help my to do it please .
i write this code but don't make any thing :

```
try
{
    int nofiles = Directory.GetFiles("E:\\files", "*.txt").Length;
    nofiles++;
    StreamWriter write = new StreamWriter("E:\\files\\" + nofiles + ".txt");
    write.WriteLine(itemId);
    write.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
App.Current.Shutdown();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inter process synchronization using [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f55ddskf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) in both applications. Make sure you release Mutex as soon as possible. You need some thing like given below in all the processes accessing file to synchronize access.

```
Mutex m = new Mutex(false, "MyMutex");
m.WaitOne();
//File read or writing code goes here.   
m.ReleaseMutex();
```

> Named system mutexes are visible throughout the operating system, and
>   can be used to synchronize the activities of processes. You can create
>   a Mutex object that represents a named system mutex by using a
>   constructor that accepts a name, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: i try to use it but don't make any thing

Comment: You have to use this in both applications and give same name MyMutex